# Android: how to load specific document

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to load this document https://nis.hzs.sk/?caaml&cron=true however I have not seen structure like this anywhere else. Is this simple serialized array? How should I load it inside android? I think that the only way is to load html file, strip all html tags (and that little response window) and then read it by lines using string parser.

Thanks in forward for help

Answer (score -1):

You will need make a HTTP request.
See this library can help you.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: I know hot to download this file. I am familiar with asyncTask. The problem is I dont know how to process it